# What is the opposite of python's ord() function?

Tags: python, standard-library

I found out about Python's ord() function which returns corresponding Unicode codepoint value. But what is the opposite function, i.e. get char value by int?

Edit: I'm new to SO, and couldn't find the answer here, so decided to post in order to everyone could find it more easily, although the answer is quite obvious. Then I read this - [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and realised it was a huge mistake. Apologies. hope it **will** be useful in that sense.

Comment: well you saved me some time going through Python documentation, so I don't understand why this question would be downvoted unless it's a duplicate

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`chr()` is what you're looking for:

```
print chr(65) # will print "A"
```

Answer (score 14):

**ord(c)**

> Given a string of length one, return an integer representing the
>   Unicode code point of the character when the argument is a unicode
>   object, or the value of the byte when the argument is an 8-bit string.
>   For example, ord('a') returns the integer 97, ord(u'\u2020') returns
>   8224. This is the inverse of chr() for 8-bit strings and of unichr() for unicode objects. If a unicode argument is given and Python was
>   built with UCS2 Unicode, then the character’s code point must be in
>   the range [0..65535] inclusive; otherwise the string length is two,
>   and a TypeError will be raised.

**chr(i)**

> Return a string of one character whose ASCII code is the integer i.
>   For example, chr(97) returns the string 'a'. This is the inverse of
>   ord(). The argument must be in the range [0..255], inclusive;
>   ValueError will be raised if i is outside that range. See also
>   unichr().